# Implementing The AdMob SDK - iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I'm trying to implement the AdMob SDK, but I get these errors and warnings when I run the following code in my viewDidLoad method...

```
// Create a view of the standard size at the bottom of the screen.
// Available AdSize constants are explained in GADAdSize.h.
bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];

// Specify the ad's "unit identifier." This is your AdMob Publisher ID.
bannerView_.adUnitID = @"a15030fff8e7e98";

// Let the runtime know which UIViewController to restore after taking
// the user wherever the ad goes and add it to the view hierarchy.
bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
[self.view addSubview:bannerView_];

// Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad.
[bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
```

Here are the errors and warnings that I receive... What is wrong?

[image: xCode]

Also here are the AdMob files in my Project Navigator...

[image]

EDIT: I now receive this crash when my app starts...

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GADBannerView private]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I can think of is to go to the Build Phases tab in your Project and check the Link Binary With Libraries box. See if your "libGoogleAdMobAds.a" is there.

Comment: Now I get this crash though... 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GADBannerView private]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Then add it. Click the + button and put it there. Let me know if that works.

Comment: I see people have ran into this problem as well. The answer is here at the bottom of the page https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/#incorporating

Comment: Do not use -all_load but -ObjC instead for the linker settings.

Answer (score 1):

Add the -all_load flag to "Other Linker Flags" and it should work.